# showsMyLocationButton not showing up on Android 8

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I use `react-native-maps` and it is Okey on android 6 and lower.

But in the higher versions of Android, it does not display the `MyLocationButton`.

```
<MapView
    zoomControlEnabled

    showsMyLocationButton={true}
    showsUserLocation={true}
>
    {this.state.markers}
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

this following code works for me and show MyLocationButton.

```
  <MapView
    customMapStyle={MapStyle}
    style={styles.map}
    provider="google"
    showsUserLocation
    renderMarker={this.renderMarker}
  />
```

if at the end you can't do it, you can create a sample button and on its onPress, with `mapAnimateToRegion` go to user location.

Comment: Sorry, on which version of Android you have tested